# Does google charges for API requests made to Google Sheet, Docs, Calendar etc.,

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-docs-api

I just wanted to know **Does Google Charges us for using API for Sheets, Docs, Calendar etc**. Since when I search in google for sheets I do see information regarding Request limitations but not for pricing.

For Docs I see **All the API are free of charge". But I missed that for Google Sheet.

So rather than asking only for Google Sheet. I just wanted to know will google changes for using there API's of all the Applications(Sheets, Docs, Profile, Calendar etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Sheets API** is free of charge if you don't exceed the [limit](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits) of 500 requests per 100 seconds per project, and 100 requests per 100 seconds per user.

Same goes with the **Docs API**, if the below [limits](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/limits) are respected:

- Read requests:

  - 3000 per project per 60 seconds;
  - 300 per user per 60 seconds;
- Write requests:

  - 600 per project per 60 seconds;
  - 60 per user per 60 seconds;

The **Calendar API** has the same policy, it is free of charge if the [limit](https://developers.google.com/calendar/pricing) of 1,000,000 queries per day is not exceeded.

Essentially, you can check the status of your quota by accessing the Google Cloud Project which uses the API in question and checking the **Quotas** section.

#### Reference

- [Sheets API Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits);
- [Docs API Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/limits);
- [Calendar API Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/limits).

Comment: If this answer was useful for you, for documentation purposes please mark it as accepted. See [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Cheers!

Comment: Hi @ale13, what happens after I exceed the limits? How is that billed? I am unable to find any information regarding this. I tried to get help from GCP support, and they asked me to contact the Workspace team.

Answer (score 1):

2022/November/22

Now I see "All use of the Google Sheets API is available at no additional cost. Exceeding the quota request limits doesn't incur extra charges and your account is not billed.".
Please update your information.
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits#pricing